# Is there a way to import the Microsoft C/C++ UIAutomationCore.dll into Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, ui-automation, dllimport

I'm working with Anaconda3 and can only use Default Libraries. Is there a way to access the already installed UIAutomationCore.dll thats standard with the Windows OS now and/or other 'Standard' DLL's and import them or wrap them to create my own custom modules in Python? I'm currently using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer to this question. You CAN Import the entire UIAutomationCore.dll Library and any other Native DLL or Library by using the 'comtypes.client' and the 'ctypes' modules. Here is a link to an Already wrapped and fully functional Import for those who do not have the Import/pip Install restrictions and security concerns my team has. If like me you need to ONLY use 'Native' Imports and Libraries that come with the Anacoda3 install by Default. Then I suggest using this code to start you off for wrapping it yourself, as I have done for my specific needs. Hope this helps everyone else in there endeavors to use UIAutomationCore.

Link: [https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows/blob/master/uiautomation/uiautomation.py][1]

Code:

```
import os
import sys
from typing import (Any, Callable, Iterable, Tuple, List, Dict)  # need pip install typing for Python3.4 or lower
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import comtypes
import comtypes.client

TreeNode = Any

METRO_WINDOW_CLASS_NAME = 'Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow'  # for Windows 8 and 8.1
SEARCH_INTERVAL = 0.5  # search control interval seconds
MAX_MOVE_SECOND = 0.5  # simulate mouse move or drag max seconds
TIME_OUT_SECOND = 20
OPERATION_WAIT_TIME = 0.5
MAX_PATH = 260
DEBUG_SEARCH_TIME = False
DEBUG_EXIST_DISAPPEAR = False
S_OK = 0

IsNT6orHigher = os.sys.getwindowsversion().major >= 6
ProcessTime = time.perf_counter  #this returns nearly 0 when first call it if python version <= 3.6
ProcessTime()  # need to call it once if python version <= 3.6


class _AutomationClient:
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls) -> '_AutomationClient':
        """Singleton instance (this prevents com creation on import)."""
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls()
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.UIAutomationCore = comtypes.client.GetModule("UIAutomationCore.dll")
            self.IUIAutomation = comtypes.client.CreateObject("{ff48dba4-60ef-4201-aa87-54103eef594e}", interface=self.UIAutomationCore.IUIAutomation)
            self.ViewWalker = self.IUIAutomation.RawViewWalker
            #self.ViewWalker = self.IUIAutomation.ControlViewWalker
        except OSError as ex:
            Logger.WriteLine('Can not load UIAutomationCore.dll.\nYou may need to install Windows Update KB971513.\nhttps://github.com/yinkaisheng/WindowsUpdateKB971513ForIUIAutomation', ConsoleColor.Yellow)
            raise ex
        #Windows dll
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetClipboardData.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowDC.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.user32.OpenDesktopW.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.user32.WindowFromPoint.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.LONG
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.LONG
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalLock.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = ctypes.c_void_p


class _DllClient:
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls) -> '_DllClient':
        """Singleton instance (this prevents com creation on import)."""
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls()
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        binPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "bin")
        os.environ["PATH"] = binPath + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
        load = False
        if sys.maxsize > 0xFFFFFFFF:
            try:
                self.dll = ctypes.cdll.UIAutomationClient_VC140_X64
                load = True
            except OSError as ex:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                self.dll = ctypes.cdll.UIAutomationClient_VC140_X86
                load = True
            except OSError as ex:
                pass
        if load:
            self.dll.BitmapCreate.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
            self.dll.BitmapFromWindow.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
            self.dll.BitmapFromWindow.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
            self.dll.BitmapFromFile.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, )
            self.dll.BitmapFromFile.restype = ctypes.c_size_t
            self.dll.BitmapToFile.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p)
            self.dll.BitmapRelease.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, )
            self.dll.BitmapGetWidthAndHeight.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, )
            self.dll.BitmapGetPixel.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
            self.dll.BitmapSetPixel.argtypes = (ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_uint)

            self.dll.Initialize()
        else:
            self.dll = None
            Logger.WriteLine('Can not load dll.\nFunctionalities related to Bitmap are not available.\nYou may need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010/2015 Redistributable Package.', ConsoleColor.Yellow)
    def __del__(self):
        if self.dll:
            self.dll.Uninitialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a sense.

First of all, install the Python module from the command prompt using:

```
pip install uiautomation
```

You can install it for everyone by right-clicking on the Windows icon and selecting 'Command Prompt (Admin)' if you wish.

To use this this product within Python the most statement to use would be:

```
import uiautomation
```

This makes all items in the module available to your script. For instance, you can access

```
uiautomation.CalendarControl
```

using the usual Python syntax.

Comment: I'm looking more for default, pre-installed, imports. Or the ability to call on native .net framework dll's. Installing anything would require "Red Tape" to get it approved for installation. Also, are all of the modules from the UIAutomation.dll available in win32gui and win32api?

Comment: OK. I dunno but I doubt it since I see that the main file is about 360 Kb. Better you should ask the author of the product.